# Expansion of $x \log \left(\frac{l+x}{x} \right)$ about x=0

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've read that

$$x \log \left(\frac{l+x}{x} \right)=x \log \frac{l}{x} + O(x^2).$$

I tried to derive this using the usual Taylor series method but kept getting a division by zero. Could anyone explain how this identity is derived?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but do note that $\frac{l+x}{x} = \frac{l}{x}+\frac{x}{x} = \frac{l}{x} + 1$. But perhaps your Taylor series method already made use of this?

Answer (score 0):

$$x \log \left(\frac{l+x}{x} \right)=x \log(l/x) + x \log(1 + x/l) = x \log(l/x) + xO(x) = x \log(l/x) + O(x^2).$$